# systemd on LTS 14.04 Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, upstart, systemd

Folks, I am wondering if systemd work on 14.04 LTS? I don't need fully replace from Upstart to systemd, because of future planning, we might want to config service running via systemd instead of Upstart even we are on 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. `systemd` is designed to run as "pid 1" and there can only be one "pid 1" on your system at a time.

For the purpose of future-proofing your app, you could try running Ubuntu 16.04 inside Docker on 14.04, or simply rent a 16.04 server to test with periodically, on AWS or another service.

I think it's very likely you will find that `systemd` can replace whatever you are using Upstart for, so you can also likely defer your `systemd` testing until it's close to the time to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.